# Discord.py emoji reaction in my ticket system doesn't work?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, ticket-system

I wanted to make a ticket system with a close command. But it doesn't work. I do get the embed message but when I react to the message nothing happens. I don't even get an error.

This is my code:

```
@bot.command(name='Close', aliases=['close'])
async def close(ctx):
    if ctx.message.channel.name.startswith('ticket'):
        msg = 'The ticket is closed. If you aren\'t done yet react to this message with , if you are react with ️'
        embed = discord.Embed(title='Closed ticket', description=msg)
        message = await ctx.send(content=None, embed=embed)
        await message.add_reaction('')
        await message.add_reaction('️')
        await ctx.message.channel.set_permissions(ctx.author, send_messages=False, read_messages=True)
        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ['', '️']
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
        if reaction.emoji == '️':
            countdown = await ctx.send('**Ticket will be closed in 10 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 9 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 8 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 7 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 6 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 5 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 4 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 3 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 2 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 1 second**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await ctx.message.channel.delete()
            await user.send('**Ticket is deleted**')
        if reaction.emoji == '':
            await ctx.send('**Ticket reopened**')
            await ctx.message.channel.set_permissions(user, send_messages=True)
    else:
        await ctx.send('This isnt a ticket')
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you getting any errors? Which of the emojis does not work?

Comment: Try to replace `if reaction.emoji == '️':` by `if str(reaction.emoji) == '️':`, because reaction.emoji may be few types and only one of them is string ([reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Reaction.emoji))

Comment: @Dominik none of them works. And i get no errors

Comment: @Baptiste Tried that but doesn't work for me

Comment: Have you imported the `members` Intent or something? I do not know if that is somehow connected to each other.

Comment: Are you sure that you first condition returns True? Can you verify this?

Comment: ```intent = discord.Intents(members=True, messages=True, guilds=True, presences=True, dm_messages=True) ```
These are my intends

Comment: I get the embed with the emojis. That works its only the reactions that dont work

Comment: OK, so try to print you reaction.emoji to see what is returned

Comment: ```def check(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ['', '️']
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
        print(reaction.emoji)```

I have it like this and i dont get anything

Comment: Maybe instead of using emojis in your code use their unicodes? like this `str(reaction.emoji) in ['\U0001f5d1', '\U0001f513']`.

Comment: nope doesn't work ):